# Android Studio Symbol R is not Defined cannot resolve symbol "R"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

A common problem with android studio is that the symbol "R" is not defined. I know you can fix this by building the project again, but I do not know if there is a permanent fix for it. It happens every five minutes and gets quite annoying. I am using android studio 2 (i am unsure of exact version). If there is no permanent fix, can someone recommend a way to develop android apps alternatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Click on Build -> Rebuild Project and then click Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.**